# Javascript error handling, error message is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I'm trying to add error handling to my submit form, but I'm not getting any error messages back..
There is a field for a url and when this url is set, a preview element loads this file and shows the file in the preview.

This function returns errors if there are any and that part works, but with the information I found online the message should be inside event.target.error/event.target.message, but both these variables are undefined..

```
$('.preview-element', '.file-upload').on('error', function(event){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleFileUpload(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    // Handle successful file load
    const fileContent = e.target.result;
    // Show file content or perform other actions
    $('.preview-element').text(fileContent);
  };

  reader.onerror = function (e) {
    // Handle file load error
    const errorMessage = e.target.error.message;
    // Display error message or perform other error handling
    console.error('File load error:', errorMessage);
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}

$('.file-upload').on('change', handleFileUpload);
```

Hope it will help!!

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work.. I'm not getting the actual error messages.. e.target.error is always undefined in my case.. Could it have something to do with mac/google chrome?